# Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::karyawan does not exist - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, authentication, session, laravel-8

I'm having a problem with my Auth. So, I'm doing login but not using User models. I made my own models called Karyawan.

The error is:

> Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::karyawan does not exist.

This is the public function on my **controller**:

```
  public function admin() 
{
    return view('admin', [
        "title" => "Admin",
        "karyawan" => Karyawan::all()
    ]);
}
```

This is the **auth.php**

```
return [

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Karyawan::class,
    ],
],

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],
```

my **Karyawan models**:

```
namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Cuti;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\Divisi;
use App\Models\Jabatan;
use App\Models\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Karyawan extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = ['karyawan_id'];
    protected $table = 'karyawans';

    public function scopeSearch($query, array $searchs) {

        $query->when($searchs['search'] ?? false, function($query, $search) {
            return $query->where('nama', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('divisi_id', 'like', '%' . $search . '%') 
            ->orWhere('jabatan_id', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('agama', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
            ->orWhere('nik', 'like', '%' . $search . '%'); 
        });
    }

    public function role_id()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }

    public function divisi()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Divisi::class);
    }

    public function jabatan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Jabatan::class);
    }

    public function cuti()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Cuti::class);
    }
}
```

and this is the **view** I want to display:

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center link-dark text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          <img src="/images/avatar/avatar-2.png" alt="" width="32" height="40" class="rounded-circle me-2">
          <strong>{{ auth()->karyawan()->nama }}</strong>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser2">
          <li>
            <form action="">
              <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item">Logout</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

<main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
      <h1 class="h2" style="position:absolute margin: auto auto"><p></p>Profil Pengguna</h1>
    </div>
    <center>
      <img src="/images/avatar/avatar-2.png" style="width: 200px">
      <p><h1>Selamat Datang, {{ auth()->karyawan()->nama }}</h1> </p>
      <p> Divisi: {{ auth()->divisi()->nama_divisi }}</p>
      <p> Jabatan: {{ auth()->jabatan()->nama_jabatan }}</p>
      <p> Role: {{ auth()->role()->nama_role }}</p>
      <p> Sisa cuti Anda: {{ auth()->karyawan()->sisa_cuti }}</p>
    </center>
  </div>
</main>
```

PS: The login auth is successful, not failed. the only problem is it can't display who is the user doing the login.

Comment: just run `php artisan config:clear` each time you change something in the guard

Comment: so, I need to change all 'users' into 'karyawans' and run clear config like that?

Comment: no, your configuration seems correct. Just sometimes when you change `auth.php`, the changes doesnt apply directly, force the load of your modification with `php artisan config:clear` but your guard is still named `web` not `karyawan`

Comment: Also, `auth()->karyawan()` doesnt work, when you call auth, specify the guard as a parameter of the helper like this `auth('web')` and the auth helper has a method user to retrieve the authenticated entity no matter the class of that entity so use `auth()->user()` it will still return Karyawan instance (if authenticated). If you dont specify a guard, the default one will be used) `'defaults' => [ 'guard' => 'web',`

Comment: auth('web')->user()->nama is works, but Attempt to read property "nama" on Null now appear.

whereas I have column "name" in karyawan table and its not null

Comment: please seek some tutorials and read documentation, i cant explain in a comment how to authentify a user. if `auth()->user()` returns null then no Karyawan is authentified in the session.